# Flask. В Blueprint'е не считываются роуты

Tags: python, flask

Я не могу понять, почему Flask не воспринимает роуты с Blueprint'а, вот код

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

Auth = Blueprint('Auth', __name__)

@Auth.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
return render_template('test.html')
```

вот app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from blueprints.auth.blueprint import Auth
app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(Auth, url_prefix='/')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
return render_template('index.html')

app.run('127.0.0.1', 3000, debug=True)
```

в папке с В Blueprint'ом есть папка templates с test.html

Comment: Что значит не воспринимает?

Comment: постоянно видается ошибка 404, но я уже решил 1.5 часа спустя :)

Answer (score 1):

Я уже нашел ответ, ошибка била в

```
app.register_blueprint(Auth, url_prefix='/')
```

не нужно писать

```
url_prefix='/'
```

**p.s** я не удалю вопрос, может кому-то поможет